# PyQGIS getting the upper left coordinates with numpy

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdalwarp, numpy

my task is to create a QGIS plugin which loads a .tiff file and then snips the whole map in specified Raster like 1:25000 equals every 5 km. Im trying to do this with the gdal_warp function but for that I need shapefiles and i can't create shapefiles with random coordinates so I have to get upper left corner of the layer to start with.. One idea was with numpy, but i've got no idea how to load the layer in the 2D array If you guys got any other ideas im open for it..

Comment: Even if the title of your question is different, it seems that your goal is splitting a raster into tiles (and that you are trying to achieve this by recurring to shapefiles as masks).